# Unity C#: Modifying parameters in List of abstract elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a class holding a List of classes, derived from an abstract superclass.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ClassWithList: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Element> elements;
    public List<Element> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            if (elements == null)
                elements= new List<Element>();
            return elements;
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public abstract class Element: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected bool isClickedInList;
    public bool IsClickedInList
    {
        get { return isClickedInList; }
        set { isClickedInList = value;  }
    }
}
```

I use a custom Editor for `ClassWithList` with a ReorderableList to modify the Element entities' values.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ClassWithList))]
public class Editor_ClassWithList : Editor
{
    private ReorderableList elementList;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (elementList== null)
            elementList=
                new ReorderableList(
                    serializedObject, serializedObject.FindProperty("elements"),
                    true, true, true, true);

        elementList.drawElementCallback += DrawElement;
    }

    private void OnDisable() { elementList.drawElementCallback -= DrawElement; }

    private void DrawElement(Rect r, int i, bool active, bool focused)
    {
        Element e = elementList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue as Element;
        e.IsClickedInList = EditorGUI.Toggle(new Rect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height - 1), e.IsClickedInList);
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        elementList.DoLayoutList();
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

The list is correctly displayed and shows all elements. Clicking on the toggle button results in a correct change of the Elements `isClickedInList` value. But as soon as I press "Play" this value is overwritten as if it wouldn't be serialized.

Any ideas where things went wrong? Might the usage of `serializedObject.FindProperty("elements")` cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further testing with the provided example and comparision with my code revealed, that the issue was the GameObject being a prefab. Somehow this results in non-saving behaviour using serialized properties, although I couldn't reproduce the error.